# Image doesn't get centered all the way

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Logo image is floating about 20% to the left. Where did i go wrong?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header" id="hd">
<header>
<div class="row">
<div class="span12 pagination-centered">
<a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><img src="http://www.blabla.com/wp-content/themes/lawyer/images/logo.png"></a></div>
</div>

.container {width: 100%;}
#hd {
background-color: #405160;
}
#lg {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: There must be something outside of the code you posted.

Comment: there is another row starting after this piece of code. So, i really don't see what could it be.

Answer (score 1):

Just made all the rows fluid, and it aligned perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try below code with attached css classes.

.row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks.